# Reading csv file resulting in number format exception

Tags: java, file, csv

I am writing a csv file using csvwriter and then calling its method writeAll.After writing i am reading the same file using buffered reader which is resulting in number format exception.How can i solve it?

```
public static void writeInventoryToUpdate(List<String[]> data)throws IOException {

    String csv = "E:\\Semester 3\\PointOfSale2\\Inventory.csv";
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

    writer.writeAll(data);
    writer.close();        
}


public void initInventory() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    BufferedReader readInventory=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Semester 3\\PointOfSale2\\Inventory.csv"));

    String line=readInventory.readLine();

    StringTokenizer nextItem;
    while(line!=null){
        nextItem=new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        while(nextItem.hasMoreTokens()){
            int productID=Integer.parseInt(nextItem.nextToken()); //Exception occuring here
            int quantity=Integer.parseInt(nextItem.nextToken());
            Inventory inventory=new Inventory(productID, quantity);
            inStock.add(inventory);
            line=readInventory.readLine();
        }
    }
    readInventory.close();
}
```

Comment: By editing your question to show us the code and the full stack trace, and marking the line where the problem occurs in the code.

Comment: There really is not much we can help you with until you show us the format of your CSV files or the code used to write/read them - you must help us help you

Comment: public static void writeInventoryToUpdate(List<String[]> data)throws IOException{
     String csv = "E:\\Semester 3\\PointOfSale2\\Inventory.csv";
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));
    writer.writeAll(data);
    writer.close();        
    }

Comment: Are you using a custom CSV writer that you wrote or can you provide a link to what you are using?

Comment: Also include an example of the csv file, although the stack trace should show you what line the exception is occurring on, so you can see what field it's trying to read. Also note that csv files can have headers and the fields may be quoted, neither of which you handle.

Comment: Debug it? What is nextItem.nextToken()? You should learn how to debug an app before asking for help.

Comment: it is reading the next element in file.

Comment: Can anyone please help.i have attached all the code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly the right idea, but with some issues on it's flow

```
BufferedReader readInventory=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Semester 3\\PointOfSale2\\Inventory.csv"));

for(String line = readInventory.readLine(); line != null; line = readInventory.readLine())
{
    StringTokenizer nextItem = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
    if(nextItem.countTokens() >= 2)
    {
        int productID = Integer.parseInt(nextItem.nextToken());
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(nextItem.nextToken());
        Inventory inventory=new Inventory(productID, quantity);
        inStock.add(inventory);
    }
}
readInventory.close();
```

Here's something that should work given the input

```
12345,67890
15243,60798
3,6
77,12355678,123 //anything past the first two values are ignored
555
777,333 //and single value things are skipped
```

Without seeing what kind of CSV files you're trying to parse, I can't give you much better of a solution

But for the most basic form of CSV file (two int values separated by a comma), this should work fine